# transform: translate and unwanted scrolling/dragging the element it's applied to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having serious trouble completing a project because of this.

I need to have an element animated with hw transitions, so I am using transform:translate, but after the animation completes you can still touch drag the element or scroll it using the middle mouse button even though I have overflown the parent element (in case of my example the body). I can't use absolute positioning so using left:290px; is out of the question.

Any ideas? I have spent loads of time on this one.

```
<html>
<style>
body {
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
#myelem {
  width:1800px;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
  transform:translate(290px,0);
  -ms-transform:translate(290px,0); 
  -webkit-transform:translate(290px,0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
<body>
   <div id="myelem">
     test
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Jsfiddle with the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/ztHgf/

Comment: I dont think that your fiddle is displaying correct? All i see is a red div with test in it? It isn't transformed at all.

Comment: the fiddle works as it should. It is a transformed:translated(290px) layer. If you middle click anywhere inside the fiddle window, you can see that when moving your mouse sideways the element also scrolls, which it shouldn't since I have an overflown body

Comment: updated the jsfiddle slightly to match its needs and make the element a bit higher http://jsfiddle.net/ztHgf/2/

Comment: What I am looking for is for a way for #myelem to stay PUT and not be able to move at all after it's translated in the X direction. Also this element cannot be fixed (that would solve my problems, but causes other problems in my project)

Comment: I guess i am not sure what you are looking for here i dont see it doing anything in Chrome, FF or IE i have clicked and scrolled the mouse button and nothing happens just black text in a red div.

Comment: middle click, scroll sideways.. I can see it in all browsers :/

Comment: `overflow:hidden` doesn't do what you think it does. unless you explicitly set the with of the body to something specific. Which means that both `body` and `html` need to be set to `width:100%`. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ztHgf/3/)

Comment: the trick was that you put overflow-x:hidden at the html element. Although this answers the question asked in this thread, it didn't solve me specific project problem, however I managed to do it with another way. Thanks for the help though, I appreciate your efforts. Adding overflow-x to the html was something new to me.